# PHP return value of an array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I would like to onsubmit, fetch the positioning of all the divs on the page and return the ids of the divs and the absolute positioning values.

This is the result I get in the console of how the array looks:
[Object { name="app1", coord="10,10"}, Object { name="app2", coord="60,10"}]

One, am I populating the array correctly? Two, how can I print it and return a string via result?

HTML page:

```
var apps = $(".block"),
            positions = [];

            $.each(apps, function (index, app) {
                var positionInfo = $(app).position();
                var input = $(this).attr('id');
                var lines = input.split('_');
                var appname = lines[0];

                positions.push({value: appname + "," + positionInfo.top + "," + positionInfo.left});
                console.log(appname + ":" + positionInfo.top + ":" + positionInfo.left);
            });

            $.ajax({
                type:  'post',
                cache:  false ,
                url:  'result_savechange.php',
                data:  {result:positions},
                success: function(resp) {
                    $('#mainCanvas').html(''); // Clear #content div
                    $('#mainCanvas').append(resp);
                } 
            });
```

PHP page:

```
<?php 
    $string = '';

    foreach($_POST["result"] as $position){
        $string .= $position['value'];
    }

    echo $string;
?>
```

Comment: json_decode("$data",true); to json_decode($data,true);

Comment: Looks fine to me. Where are you stuck exactly? json_decode in PHP will let you see that as an array, which you can then manipulate how you want before echoing json_encode and returning any values you want for the JS to use.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST["result"]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason to use JSON here.  It's overkill for this scenario.  Just do this:

```
$.ajax({
    type:  'post',
    cache:  false ,
    url:  'result_savechange.php',
    data:  {result: positions},
    success: function(resp) {
        alert(resp);
    } 
});
```

Then in PHP, `$_POST["result"]` will be an array.

```
foreach($_POST["result"] as $position){
    echo $position['name'];
    echo $position['coord'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. Will flag as the right answer regardless, but would you have an idea why the alert(resp) is not working?

Comment: Does your `result_savechange.php` echo anything?

Comment: Updated my original post with the code. Yes it should be echoing a string of the array results.

Comment: So, you're not seeing anything in your `#mainCanvas`?

Comment: No, it doesn't even clear, so I guess the call wasn't successful.

Comment: Check your console for errors.  Also check its network tab to see if the AJAX call is ran.

Comment: @user1067577 try using webdeveloper tools in your browser (google it) and you'll see the network traffic - thus if your script got called and what it replied and so on. And do not forget to flag that answer :D

Comment: Yes I've been using firebug but not seeing errors. Will keep trying

Comment: Changed a few things around that had nothing to do with the above code and it works now, thanks again!